# How to create an IAM role of specific type using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

I'm trying to lock down a user to a specific `VPC` in `AWS` and following [How to Help Lock Down a User’s Amazon EC2 Capabilities to a Single VPC | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-help-lock-down-a-users-amazon-ec2-capabilities-to-a-single-vpc/).

It is mentioned that we need to create an `IAM role` with name `VPCLockDown` of type `AWS Service`

[image: IAM role type]

and add the services for which the role needs access to. like `ec2`, `lambda` etc.

I was trying to create this role programatically using `boto3`.

I checked the [create_role documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_role) for creating a role using `boto3`.

However, they haven't mentioned anything to specify the type of role and the services that I can specify that the role should have access to.

Is there any way to specify these items while creation of the `IAM role` using `boto3`

**Edit1:**

I tried creating a service_linked_role as per **Sudarshan Rampuria**'s answer like

```
response = iam.create_service_linked_role(
            AWSServiceName='ec2.amazonaws.com',
        )
```

But getting the following error:

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
>   CreateServiceLinkedRole operation: Cannot find Service Linked Role
>   template for ec2.amazonaws.com

Comment: The documentation says "The role's trust policy is created at the same time as the role, using CreateRole. You can update a role's trust policy using UpdateAssumeRolePolicy.". Therefore, it seems that you need to use [`update_assume_role_policy()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.update_assume_role_policy) to provide a new Trust Policy. (That blog post is 4 years old, so it might have a few discrepancies.)

Comment: BTW, what is your goal in limiting users to a specific VPC? What is the business situation that you are wanting to enable? Is it just the ability to launching instances in a given VPC, or is it to also do other VPC-related actions?

Comment: It's just about launching the instances for now.

Comment: It would probably be easier to simply apply the policy directory to the IAM User, rather than using a role. (Does that make sense, or would you need an example?)

Comment: An example would be much helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use create_service_linked_role() function boto3 to link a role to a service.
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.create_service_linked_role

Comment: Updated question after trying this.

Comment: If you could point to examples for using `create_service_linked_role`, that would be much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a policy that allows a **specific IAM User** to launch an instance (`RunInstances`), but only in a given VPC:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EC2RunInstancesVPC",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:subnet/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:vpc": "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:vpc/vpc-abcd1234"  <--- Change this
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "RemainingRunInstancePermissions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:instance/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2::image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:key-pair/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:ap-southeast-2:111111111111:security-group/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

You might need to change the Region. (I tested it in the Sydney region.)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this for Lambda, we get the similar error mentioned by the question author under "Edit". Lambda doesn't have a service linked role. You can see from the [AWS Lambda documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html) that "create-role" is used for creating lambda execution role.
You can also see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) that only Lambda@Edge has service linked role.

One just needs to use use boto3 create-role with a policy document

```
        response = iam_client.create_role(
        RoleName="some-role-name",
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument='{"Version": "2012-10-17","Statement": [{ "Effect": "Allow", "Principal": {"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"}, "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"}]}',
        Description='Lambda role'
    )
```